# Why is firestore not rendering a collection?

Tags: firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore

I want to get a collection from my firestore, I currently have 3 collections, `users`, `playlists`, and `test`

This is my code:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <form @submit.prevent="handleSubmit">
      <input type="text" required placeholder="Example Title" v-model="title" />
      <p>{{ error }}</p>
    </form>
    <div>{{ documents }}</div>
    <div v-if="error" class="error">Could not fetch the data</div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import useCollection from "@/composables/useCollection";
import getCollection from "@/composables/getCollection";
import { ref } from "@vue/reactivity";
export default {
  setup() {
    const title = ref("");
    const { addDoc } = useCollection("test");
    const { error, documents } = getCollection("users");

    const handleSubmit = async () => {
      await addDoc({
        title: title.value,
      });
      title.value = "";
    };

    return {
      handleSubmit,
      title,
      error,
      documents,
    };
  },
};
</script>

<style></style>
```

The problem is that when I try to render the collection`users`, it does not work. But when I render the`playlists` collection, it does work.

Is there maybe something in the database that I have to do?

Edit: These are my firestore rules:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if
          request.time < timestamp.date(2022, 2, 2);
    }
  }
}
```

And this is my structure:
[image]

This is my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "examples",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@tiptap/extension-heading": "^2.0.0-beta.26",
    "@tiptap/extension-placeholder": "^2.0.0-beta.46",
    "@tiptap/starter-kit": "^2.0.0-beta.174",
    "@tiptap/vue-3": "^2.0.0-beta.89",
    "core-js": "^3.6.5",
    "firebase": "^8.0.1",
    "vue": "^3.0.0",
    "vue-router": "^4.0.0-0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-router": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-service": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/compiler-sfc": "^3.0.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi @Emiel Van de Veire, Could you please include your Firestore Rules and Firestore Structure on your post for us to be able replicate your issue.

Comment: I did, could you please check it out?

Comment: Hi @Emiel Van de Veire, I still wasn't able to replicate your issue. May I ask for a reproducible code rather so that we can clone and have a try to replicate. Also, please include your `package.json`. I also tried using [Vuefire](https://vuefire.vuejs.org/vuefire/querying.html#one-time-read) and I have rendered the data successfully without any error. You may check this [repository](https://github.com/marcbrs/vuejs-query/blob/main/index.js) for sample query I created.